# relative import from __init__.py file throws error

Tags: python, relative-import

So I'm using a template set by a co-worker and as a newbie to python I may be missing something very obvious.

The main directory has the init file which has a module I need for the main python file that generates the error.

Co-worker used:

```
from . import X
```

Where X was the module, but when copying this (and a populated init file) to my own directory it generates this error:

> ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

From google and SO I gather that this is perfectly fine and logical so I'm wondering, as a newbie, what I've missed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attempted relative import in non-package even with \_\_init\_\_.py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py)

Comment: In that suggestion he's pulling from a standard .py file. My problem is about pulling from a __init__.py file.

Comment: But your problem has the same cause.  I hope my answer clarifies the reason for your error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to understand how Python handles modules.

When you start the interpreter with a script, this script becomes the main module, with the matching name `__main__`.

When using `import`, other modules are searched in the search path, that you can also access (and change) using `sys.path`. The first entry of `sys.path` is usually empty and stands for the current directory.

A directory within the search path is a package if it contains a `__init__.py` file.

Now, when you execute a script within a directory that contains an `__init__.py` file, this script will become `__main__` and the directory is not regarded as a package, as it is not in `sys.path`!

For example, consider the following directory layout:

```
root/
    pkg/
        __init__.py
        b.py
        c.py
    a.py
```

When you run `python a.py` from the `root/` directory, you can import `pkg/` and use relative imports within this package (e.g., `from . import c` in `b.py` or `__init__.py`).

When you run `python b.py` from the `pkg` directory, you cannot use relative imports since Python does not recognize `pkg` as a package: it is not in `sys.path`. For Python, `pkg` is an ordinary directory, no matter if it contains a `__init__.py`.  The fully qualified name of `c.py` is just `c`, not `pkg.c`, so a relative `from . import c` won't work.

Comment: I think I understand. Because the use of relative import is local to a folder it will generate the error as the referencing is sort of circular. Which is odd that my co-worker uses this tactic throughout his scripts. Most of what he codes looks fairly logical and watertight, maybe he has a Jenkins extension or something that parses it.

Comment: \_\_init\_\_.py is no longer required for python 3.3+