# Python not able to find my module even it exists

Tags: python

My folder structure is

```
fold1/fold2/a.py
fold1/fold3/b.py
fold1/fold3/c.py
```

a.py is doing

```
from fold1.fold3 import c
```

c.py is doing

```
import b
```

When I run a.py, I am getting error "No module named b"

I have `__init__.py` in all folders, but still why I am getting that error.

I know that lastly python checks for packages in current directory, so here current directory is "fold2" and I am not finding "b.py" in that fold2? but both "c.py" and "b.py" are in same directories right but still why I am getting that error?

Edit: The code is generated by pyxb python module, so I cannot change import statements.

Comment: easiest no brainer solution is to download pycharm, delete all your import statements, and let pycharm take care of your imports

Comment: The problem is that the import path has nothing to do with the location of the file doing the import.  It is determined solely with the cwd at the time Python was invoked, as plus any changes made to `sys.path` (and the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable).

Comment: `import b` is saying i expect b is in PYTHONPATH (which is not the case, its in PYTHONPATH/fold1/fold3) so import b from there. `from . import b` is saying in my context, `b` is in the relative path `.` so import from there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [relative import from \_\_init\_\_.py file throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942650/relative-import-from-init-py-file-throws-error)

Comment: Also see [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time).

Answer (score 1):

`import b` is an *absolute* import: `b` has to be found in a package listed in `sys.path`.

In order to import `b` relative to the package containing `c`, use the relative import

```
from . import b
```

`.` refers to the package containing `c` (`fold3`). `..` would refer to the package containing *that* package (`fold1`). You could also write

```
from ..fold3 import b
```

`..` refers to `fold1`, so `..fold3` refers to the module `fold3` in the package `fold1`.

When using relative imports, it doesn't matter where `fold1` exists: it could be in `sys.path`, it could be a submodule of some other package. As long as the internal structure of `fold1` remains the same, the relative imports will continue to work the same.

Answer (score 0):

All the paths are relative to where you start the interpreter from!

`c.py` is looking for `b` in the parent of `fold1`

try using a form like `from fold1.fold3 import b` instead